# Python - Variable name/value to dict key/value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Is there any way in Python to build a dict from variable name/value to key/value without assigning explicitly?

```
def my_func(var1, var2):
  my_dict = dict(var1 , var2)
  print(my_dict)

my_func("x", "y")
```

Prints:

```
{"var1": "x", "var2": "y"}
```

Edited in order to make it less artificial. The idea is to avoid `dict(var1=var1)`

Comment: The example is artificial, why not build the dict directly without first creating the variables `var1` and `var2`?

Comment: You're asking how to make a dictionary with specified keys and values?  Well, `my_dict = {'var1': var1, 'var2': var2}`.  Unless I'm missing something...?

Comment: not sure if that what you meant but you could do `dict(var1=var1, var2=var2)`

Comment: But in one form or another, you are going to have to specify `'var1'` and `'var2'` explicitly as string constants. Where you write `var1`, this means: the object to which the name `var1` refers. That object itself contains no concept of any variable name to which it might be assigned, and indeed the same object can be assigned to multiple variables.

Comment: also consider using kwargs

Answer (score 3):

```
var1 = "x"
var2 = "y"

my_dict = dict(var1=var1, var2=var2)

print(my_dict)
```

Prints:

```
{'var1': 'x', 'var2': 'y'}
```

Comment: My idea is to do perform this without assigning `var1=var1` @andrej-kesely

Answer (score 0):

You can get them from the locals() dict

```
var1 = "x"
var2 = "y"
my_dict  = {k: v for k, v in locals().items() if k in ['var1','var2']}
print(my_dict)
```

Output

```
{'var1': 'x', 'var2': 'y'}
```